# Thinking Sphinx- order by year and relevance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, thinking-sphinx

I'm using ThinkingSphinx as search engine on webpage. What I need is to sort search result by year and relevance.

As `order: "DATE_FORMAT(created_at, '%Y') DESC"` doesn't work and Time segments aren't useful at all for what I want, I'm getting out of ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `YEAR` function does what you need, but it's worth noting that you'll need to use it in the SELECT clause, give the result an alias, and then refer to that alias in your ORDER clause.

This is presuming you're using TS v3:

```
Model.search 'foo',
  :select => '*, YEAR(created_at) as created_at_year, weight() as weight',
  :order  => 'created_at_year DESC, weight DESC'
```

Comment: Any solution for TS v2? As this project is dependent on Rails 3.0 and can't be updated.

Comment: For TS v2, try changing `:select` to `:sphinx_select`. I think that should be all that's needed.

Answer (score 0):

Working code for Thinking Sphinx V2 on OSX with Sphinx 2.1.6

```
:sphinx_select => "*, YEAR(created_at) as created_at_year", :order => "created_at_year DESC, weight() DESC")
```

Code for Thinking Sphinx V2 on BSD with Sphinx 2.0.6

```
:sphinx_select => "*, YEAR(created_at) as created_at_year, weight() as my_weight", :order => "created_at_year DESC, my_weight DESC") # can't be aliased as weight!
```